# Could not connect to eureka server from docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I'm trying connection to eureka server from docker container.

The eureka server is running via "java -jar eureka-server.jar" command.
The eureka client is running on docker container.

Eureka server configuration is:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekaserver
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8080/eureka/
```

Eureka client configuration is:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client-application
server:
  port: 8081
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8080/eureka/
```

I also tried to setup directly ip-address for example

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://1.2.3.4:8080/eureka/
```

But, unfortunately, I'm facing with stack trace:

```
[2019-05-26 09:44:14.714] slf4j - 1  INFO [main] --- o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClient: Retrying connect to {}-> http://eurekaserver:8080
[2019-05-26 09:44:15.717] slf4j - 1 ERROR [main] --- c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient: Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

And it is cause of

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

So my question is how to resolve connectivity?
Docker and eureka are placed on the same machine, because the command `curl "http://1.2.3.4:8080/eureka/apps"` returns app to me

How can I do some investigating, why a docker cannot resolve the host?

p.s. I've known about issue, when eureka-client looks at localhost hostname, but looks like my issue another.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
The cause of the issue was, don't use

```
registerWithEureka: true
fetchRegistry: true
```

More about, find at first links after typing properties name in google

But if you use them, then you have to set `serviceUrl` as hostname and also add 
`instance.preferUseIpAddress: true`

p.s. Not sure that is fully can solve this problem, but that, I have changed at application config.